# HDInsight Hadoop Cluster (Windows) has any way to monitor the CPU usage?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-hdinsight

I have created a windows based HDInsight Cluster (v3.2), and I want to monitor my cluster's system metrics such as CPU usage, memory and Disk I/O, but seems the Ambari API is only partially supported, do we have a way to do this kind of work?

Comment: Can you install an scollector agent on the nodes: http://bosun.org/scollector/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically all depends on whether you have a Windows-based HDInsight cluster or a Linux-based HDInsight cluster.

On Linux-based clusters, you can point your browser to https://.azurehdinsight.net to access the Ambari web UI. It gives you access to monitoring (status information and alerts related to different processes), metrics (e.g. CPU, Disk, Memory, Network usage), heat maps and lots of details about the different services. You can also start, stop and restart components and services.

On Windows-based clusters, you're much more limited. First, you do not have access to the Ambari web UI. You can only use the Ambari REST API (meaning, you'll need to write your own application using this API). And the API currently only supports monitoring. So there is currently no way to get access to metrics like CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

Which usage data are you trying to monitor and is not available.

Take a look at Amabri web on HDINSIGHT Linux clusters which shows graphs for CPU, memory and disk usage. Its powered by the Ambari API which is available on both Windows and Linux clusters.